# C#/.NET - Better way to organize

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` named `MyForm` and two nested `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` named `MyPanel` and `MyOtherPanel`. Inside each panel, there are buttons, labels, etc. Is there a way to split `MyPanel` and `MyOtherPanel` into another class and render them in the GUI as `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`.

The main purpose of my question is to avoid populating the name space of `MyForm`.

Thanks!

Comment: Try giving your classes meaningful names and stop using daft prefixes ;)

Comment: partial classes ?

Comment: a panel is just a container control - unless you will be referencing it in code a lot, why does it need a name at all?

Comment: If you need code reuse or you are creating multiple instances of the panel (like in a dashboard app) then Custom User Controls may be of use to you. Otherwise you are looking for a perceived efficiency that will not give you any real benefit.

Comment: @SqlSurfer Thanks I'll look into that!

Answer (score 0):

To organize WinForm code better, One important design consideration you can make, that is to have each form a Handler. So your code is separate from WinForm.cs. For Example, you can have MyFormHandler.cs, Which holds/Implements your MyPanel1 and MyOtherPanel1 logic. It is a better approach to separate your code from .NET Winform code and easy to reuse, extend and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class to inherit a panel. Then you can override whatever properties or methods you want changed from the panel. In which case when you call them from your main form or MyForm you will need to initialize them i.e.

```
void main(){
    MyPanelClass meaningfulpanelname = new MyPanelClass();
    meaningfulpanelname.Show();

}

public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
  protected override void functionToOverride(EventArgs e)
  {
      //what you want done
   }
}
```

I have included .Show() because I don't remember whether when creating dynamically in C# you need to do so or not.

Since it is in a Windows Form Application I am taking a guess that you do.

I could also see the syntax being

```
this.Controls.Add(meaningfulpanelname);
```

within void main() instead of

```
meaningfulpanelname.Show();
```